# Prove that ((S − T) ∩ (S ∩ T)) = ∅.

Tags: logic, proof-writing, solution-verification

I am still learning proofs and I am a little stuck. I think I have the first couple of steps I am just unsure how to finish it off.  Any help would be appreciated.

((S − T) ∩ (S ∩ T))

[{x|x ∈ S ∩ x ∈ T} x ∈ S ∩{x|x ∈ S ∩ x ∈ T}]

[{x ∈ S ∩ x ∈ T} x ∈ S ∩{x ∈ S ∩ x ∈ T}]

...

True. Q.E.D

Answer (score 2):

We know,
$$S-T=S\cap T^C$$
So,
\begin{align*}
(S-T)\cap (S\cap T)&=S\cap T^C\cap S\cap T\\
&=S\cap (T\cap T^C)\\
&=\emptyset
\end{align*}
Does that help?